# How to log all sql going through JBoss datasource with log4j

Tags: sql, logging, jboss, log4j

I've looked at log4jdbc (which does not support datasources), [p6spy](http://www.p6spy.com/) which seems to be what I am looking for but it has not been updated since 2003 which makes me nervous and lists only JBoss 3.x (we use JBoss 5), and JAMon which seems heavyweight for what I am trying to accomplish (a simple log of all SQL statements running through a JBoss application server).

I was hoping that JBoss itself would have a switch to log all the sql (as Websphere does) but I cannot find any documentation for it so that functionality might not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking at this question:
[jdbcdslog](http://code.google.com/p/jdbcdslog/) may do exactly this...